# ¿como se configura los valores de php en un archivo .htaccess bajo el servidor web apache?

Tags: php, .htaccess, apache2

hola estoy tratando de modificar los valores de php como:

- memory_limit
- date.timezone
  etc.

sin embargo como estoy el caso es de un hosting compartido no hay de otra mas que usar un archivo .htaccess para hacer esto pero hay un problema, al hacer esto en un hosting con servidor litespeed esto es fácil y no hay problema pero el problema es cuando se hace esto en un hosting que tiene servidor web apache porque cuando se usa el modelo:

`php_value memory_limit 200M`

el sitio web arroja error, ¿alguien sabe como hacer esto?

Comment: En tu hosting deben informate como hacerlo. Nadie mejor que ellos debe conocerlo. ¿les has preguntado?

Comment: para un hosting gratuito es muy dificil que te responjdan en estos casos, he puesto un ticket de esto y no han contestado

Answer (score 0):

Tenes idea si el servidor tiene configurado php como un modulo de apahe o esta en modo CGI?

Si esta como modulo, probaron esto? :

```
<IfModule mod_php7.c>
    php_value memory_limit 200M
</IfModule>
```

(obvio editando la version del mod que tendan en apache)

Comment: php esta configurado exactamente en fasct cgi (fpm-fcgi)

Comment: Bueno, entoces tas en un problema con dicho host, ya que si no esta como modulo, en el archivo htaccess no vas a poder cargar esos parametros  "php_value". Lo unico que se me ocurre, es que definas dichas variables en el mismo script php: ini_set('memory_limit', '200M');